# does every non-empty open set has connected non-empty open subset

Tags: general-topology

Given an open set $O$ and a point $x \in O$, is there always a non-empty connected open set $U \subset O$ such that $x \in U$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a non-discrete totally disconnected space $X$ (for example, $\mathbb{Q}$ with the Euclidean topology). Choose $O=X$. Since $X$ is not discrete, there is an $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is not open. However, since $X$ is totally disconnected, $\{x\}$ is the only connected subset of $X$ containing $x$. Hence, there is no connected open subset containing $x$.

Comment: By Euclidean topology, you mean the topology defines by the euclidean metric?

Comment: @CuriousAlpaca Yes. Alternatively, it is the subspace topology $\mathbb{Q}$ inherits from $\mathbb{R}$ (also equipped with the topology induced by the Euclidean metric).